# limpar buffer em python cada vez que envia o valor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

tenho um raspberry a enviar dados de 15 em 15 segundos, no entanto tenho um valor que demora a atualizar, será que limpando o buffer a cada iteração no while True resolve o problema?
o meu código é o seguinte:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
import time
import subprocess
import logging
from opcua import Server
import BMP085
import mysql.connector as mysql
from datetime import datetime
import opcua
##### Sensor Data of BMP180 ######################
bmp = BMP085.BMP085()# Instantiation 
temperature =bmp.read_temperature()# variable of temperature
altitude = bmp.read_altitude()# variable of altitude
pressure = bmp.read_pressure()# variable of pressure
################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.WARNING)

# get Objects node, this is where we should put our nodes
# setup our server
server = Server()
server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://192.168.1.10:4840/freeopcua/server/")

# setup our own namespace, not really necessary but should as spec
uri = "http://192.168.1.10:4840/freeopcua/server/"
idx = server.register_namespace(uri)

# get Objects node, this is where we should put our nodes
objects = server.get_objects_node()

# populating our address space

sensordata = objects.add_object(idx, "Sensor One BMP180")

temp_var_node= sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Temperature Sensor One", temperature)
print("the temp_var_node is:", temp_var_node)
altit_var_node = sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Altitude Sensor One", altitude)
print("the altit_var_node is:", altit_var_node)
press_var_node = sensordata.add_variable(idx, "Pressure Sensor One ", pressure)
print("the pressure_var_node is:", press_var_node)
#################### Set MyVariable to be writable by clients #################################
temp_var_node.set_writable()
altit_var_node.set_writable()
press_var_node.set_writable()
# starting de server OPCUA!
server.start()
try:

    while True:

        temp_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_temperature())   
        altit_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_altitude())
        press_var_node.set_value(bmp.read_pressure())
        time.sleep(1)

        temp = temp_var_node.get_value()#get the node value of temp_var_node
        print("The value of temp_var_node is:", temp)
        altit = altit_var_node.get_value()#get the node value of altit_var_node
        print("The value of altit_var_node is:", altit)
        press = press_var_node.get_value()#get the node value of press_var_node
        print("The value of press_var_node is:", press)
        time.sleep(1)
finally:
server.stop()
```

Comment: Você fala da impressão na tela?

Comment: não,  é quando o valor é enviado por rede Ethernet, pergunto isto porque tenho um sensor magnetico que demora a atualizar o valor quando aproximo ou afasto um íman.